# Stuck at booting Ubuntu 12.10 on iMac (late 2012)

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, boot-camp, imac

So i've installed bootcamp windows on my mac already and created a extra partition for installing ubuntu 12.10. However i've downloaded the image from ubuntu, then burnt the iso to the DVD, boot my mac with holding the "C" button to load the disc image, it loads but eventually stucks at [this screen](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3826499/photo.JPG). Is there any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Try restarting the boot process a few more times.

Comment: I've rebooted it for multiple times, i think there is some issue with the bluetooth capability and the ubuntu system, is this possible?